# Store json responses offline iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, json, ipad, nsuserdefaults

I am new to iOS,

My app is purely Login based app, to make my app faster/reliable i want to remove network dependency as much as possible.

What i want to do is, i want to store json responses somewhere in my app so that next time whenever he relaunches the app, i don't need to fetch my data again from server.

**For eg:** if userId is `K123` then i want to store 4 json responses against this id, after when user does login with another account say userId `J456` then i want to store same responses with it's data and so on...

*What could be the best approach to save my responses offline?*

***Thank you in advance***

Comment: Go for coredata

Comment: @Krunal Jitendra Lathiya Techno is the app going to work in offline mode?

Comment: @TusharSharma i dont want to store all json responses but few of them i want to

Comment: @KrunalJitendraLathiyaTechno The main aim for using core data, sqlite is to make app work in offline(in case you are travelling underground and your connection goes offline, at that state it helps you save your work , and sync once network is back), to save small data you can use userDefaults. Make sure not to save token and high level information in defaults.It's used to save general purpose information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to minimize app usage on the network and wants to provide offline data, obviously you should go for the database. If you have very minimum data against user id, it's a different case. But from your question, i understood that you might going to have lots of data related to login id. Then I advise you to go with implementing **core data**.

Comment: Then please go with the database. Even though it takes time to learn and implement. It's the right way of doing it.

Comment: Please accept the answer @KrunalJitendraLathiyaTechno. It might help to person having same doubt like you ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use any **object cache** library, I'd recommend you to go with [PINCache](https://github.com/pinterest/PINCache), its very easy to use and effective.